# JavaScript only loading 10 xml nodes

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an XML script that is listing all of my products and I have a Javascript in my html page to pull the content from the XML and paginate it. Although it only allows the specified limit which is 10 to show on each page which is correct although if I have one extra is just does not display it, also if I only have 2 or 8 products for example in my xml file it does not show the content at all. Please help.

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="pagination"></div>
<script>

    var page = 1, perPage = 10, content = document.getElementById('content'),
    pagination = document.getElementById('pagination'), records;

    function paganation(page)
    {
        var nextMaxItem = perPage * page;
        var fromItem = (page - 1) * perPage;
        var maxPages = records.length / perPage;

        var xmlContent = '<div class="row">';
        for (var i = fromItem; i < nextMaxItem; i++) {
            xmlContent += '<article class="post all ';
            xmlContent += records[i].getElementsByTagName("CATEGORY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            xmlContent += '" id="">';
            xmlContent += '<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail">';
            xmlContent += '<img src="';
            xmlContent += records[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            xmlContent += '" />';
            xmlContent += '<div class="caption">';
            xmlContent += '<a href="';
            xmlContent += records[i].getElementsByTagName("LINK")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            xmlContent += '">';
            xmlContent += '<h4>';
            xmlContent += records[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            xmlContent += '</h4>';
            xmlContent += '</a>';
            xmlContent += '<p>';
            xmlContent += records[i].getElementsByTagName("SHORTDESCRIPTION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            xmlContent += '</p>';
            xmlContent += '</div>';
            xmlContent += "</div></div></article>";
        }
        xmlContent += "</div>";
        content.innerHTML = xmlContent;

        var paginationContent = "";
        var previous = page - 1;
        if (page > 1) {
            paginationContent += '<a href="javascript:paganation('+previous+');">Back</a>';
        } else {
            paginationContent += "Back";
        }

        for (var j = 1; j < Math.ceil(maxPages); j++) {
            paginationContent += " ";
            paginationContent += '<a href="javascript:paganation('+j+');">'+j+'</a>';
            paginationContent += " ";
        }

        var next = page + 1;
        if (next <= maxPages) {
            paginationContent += '<a href="javascript:paganation('+next+');">Next</a>';
        } else {
            paginationContent += "Next";
        }
        pagination.innerHTML = paginationContent;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/xml/product_catalog.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
    records = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PRODUCT");
    paganation(1);

</script>
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CATALOG>
    <!--CLEANING CHEMICALS-->
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11101 - Dishwashing Liquid Morning Plus.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Dishwashing Liquid Morning Plus 5lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Dishwashing Liquid Morning Plus Triple Concentrate Biodegradable, Non Phosphate, Septic Safe 5lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11102 Dishwashing Liquid Classic 20L.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Classic Dishwash Liquid 20lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Classic Sink Dishwashing Liquid 20lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11103 Dishwashing Liquid Lemon Fresh.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Dishwashing Liquid Lemon Fresh 1lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Dishwashing Liquid Lemon Fresh 1lt (12/ctn)</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11104 Machine Dishwash Powder ALL IN 1.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Mach D/W Powder all In One 5k</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Machine Dishwash Powder All in One 5kg Biodegradable, Non Phosphate, Septic Safe</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11107 D1 Suma Star.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>D1 Suma Star + (4 x 1.5lt/ctn)</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Suma Star Plus D1 - Dispensed Sink Detergent Ultra Concentrate (4 x 1.5lt/ctn)</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11108 L4 Machine Detergent.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>L4 (2 x 5lt/ctn)</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Suma Special L4 - Hard Water Dishwashing Detergent (2 x 5lt/ctn) DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11109 Suma Rinse A5.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>A5 (2x5lt/ctn)</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Classic Sink Dishwashing Liquid 20lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11111 Suma Unison Maxi G3 4.5KG.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>G3 (3x4.5kg/ctn)</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Suma Unison Maxi G3 - Ultra Concentrated Hard Water Dishwashing Detergent and Destainer (3 x 4.5kg/ctn) DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11112 Suma Unison Clar A2 4L.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>A2 (3x4lt/ctn)</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Suma Unison Rinse Clar A2 - Ultra Concentrate (3 x 4lt/ctn)</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11119 Machine Dishwash Liquid.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Machine Dishwash Liquid 5lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Machine Dishwash Liquid 5lt DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11120 Rinse Aid.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Rinse Aid - Machine 5lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Rinse Aid - Machine 5lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11121 Machine Dishwash Liquid - 20L.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Machine Dishwash Liquid 20lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Machine Dishwashing Liquid 20lt DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11122 Rinse Aid 20L.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Rinse Aid - Machine 20lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Rinse Aid - Machine 20lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11406 View Quick.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>View Quick - Floor Cleaner 5lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>View Quick - No Rinse Floor Cleaner 5lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11407 Stride Citrus HC.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Stride Citrus HC 2 x 2.5lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Stride Citrus HC - Neutral Cleaner 2 x 2.5lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11408 Suma Bio Floor Cleaner.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Suma Bio-floor Cleaner</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Suma Bio-Floor Cleaner 3.7lt/bottle</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11501 Suma Calc D5.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Suma Calc D5 - Descaler 2lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Suma Calc D5 - Kitchen Descaler 6x2lt/ctn DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12101 Laundry Powder - Top Loader.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Top-Load Laundry 15kg</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Laundry Powder - Premium Enzyme (Top-Load) 15kg</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12102 Laundry Powder - Front Loader.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Front-Load Laundry 12.5kg</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Enzymo Front (Front-Load Laundry Powder) 12.5kg</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12104 Laundry Liquid Premium.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Laundry Liquid Premium 5ltr</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Laundry Liquid Premium 5ltr</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12105 Fabric Softener Premium.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Fabric Softener Premium 5lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Fabric Softener Premium 5lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12206 Clax 100 OB 2AL1.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Clax 100 OB 2AL1 15ltr</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Clax 100 OB 2AL1 - Surfactant Booster 15ltr DG 9</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12208 Clax Hypo 42A1.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Clax Hypo 42A1 15ltr</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Clax Hypo 42A1 - Laundry Bleach 15ltr DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12211 Clax Soft Conc 5Dl1.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Clax Soft Conc 5DL1 15lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Clax Soft Concentrate 5DL1 - Fabric Softener 15ltr</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12215 Clax 6GL1.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Clax 6GL1 15ltr</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Clax 6GL1- Claracid Sour 15ltr DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12217 Clax 7WL1 25L.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Clax 7WL1 25lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Clax 7WL1 - Liquid Rusko 25lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12218 Clax CID 6BL1.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Clax CID 6BL1 15lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Clax CID 6BL1 - Alkalinity and Bleach Neutraliser 15lt DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/12301 Prewash Stain Remover 20L.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Pre-Wash Stain Remover 20lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Pre-Wash Stain Remover 20lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>

















    <!--Here are the nodes I am having trouble with-->
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11203 Oven - Grill Cleaner Premium.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Oven & Grill Cleaner 5LT</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Oven & Grill Cleaner Premium 5ltr DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11206 D92 Non Caustic Oven Cleaner 2L.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>D92 Non Caustic Oven Cleaner</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>D92 Non Caustic Oven Cleaner 2lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11211 Multi Purpose Degreaser.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Multi Purpose Degreaser 5ltr</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Multi Purpose Degreaser - Bio-Degradable Floor Cleaner 5ltr DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11212 Multi Purpose Degreaser 20L.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Multi Purpose Degreaser 20lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>MultI Purpose Degreaser - Bio-Degradable Floor Cleaner 20lt DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11215 Break Up JF d3.5 Conc.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Break Up JF D3.5 conc.</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Break-Up JF D3.5 Concentrate - High Foaming Degreaser 2 x 2.5lt/ctn DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11216 Break Up 5lt.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Break Up 5lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Break Up - Degreaser 5lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11303 Neutral Detergent - Sanitiser.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Neutral DetergentSanitiser 5lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Neutral Detergent/Sanitiser - Capable of Cutting Grease and Soil for Washable Surfaces, Polished Floor Cleaner 5lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11305 All Purpose Sanitiser.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>All Purpose Sanitiser</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>All Purpose Sanitiser - Food Grade for Soaking Cutlery, ideal for Equipment & Food Processing Areas Floors 5lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11310 JF 2.5lt.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>J512 JF 2 x 2.5ltr/ctn</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>J512 JF - Concentrated Sanitiser for Pre-cleaned Surfaces 2 x 2.5ltr/ctn DG 8</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11311 SUMA SAN CONC D4a.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>D4A 4x1.5kg</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Suma San Concentrated D4A - No Rinse Sanitiser (4 x 1.5lt/ctn)</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11312SUMA BAC CONCD10.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>D10 4x1.5kg</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Suma Bac Concentrated D10 - Cleaner/Sanitiser, Portion Controlled, Ultraconcentrated 4x1.5lt/ctn</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <IMAGE>/images/Products/Cleaning Chemical/11403 Floor Cleaner.jpg</IMAGE>
        <TITLE>Floor Cleaner 5lt</TITLE>
        <SHORTDESCRIPTION>Floor Cleaner - Cleans Tile, Vinyl, Lino, Ceramic Floors & Walls Toilets, Baths etc 5lt</SHORTDESCRIPTION>
        <CATEGORY>cleaning-chemicals</CATEGORY>
    </PRODUCT>
    <!--/CLEANING CHEMICALS-->
</CATALOG>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### JS Fiddle Demo


You have a loop that adds every product until `nextMaxItem`. Which is equal to `perPage * page`. So when you call it, you get `10`. But the script gives you an error, because you don't have 10, but 7. It cannot find the other ones. To avoid that error, check if it exists in the `for` loop:

```
if(records[i] === undefined) break;
```

**Edit**

Some other small changes had to be made for it to work with any product number. All the relevant lines modified have a comment with an arrow:

```
var page = 1, perPage = 10, content = document.getElementById('content'),
pagination = document.getElementById('pagination'), records;

function paganation(page)
{
    var nextMaxItem = perPage * page,
        fromItem = (page - 1) * perPage,
        maxPages = Math.ceil( records.length / perPage ), // <-----------

        xmlContent = '<div class="row">';
    for (var i = fromItem; i < nextMaxItem; i++) {
        if(records[i] === undefined) break; // <-----------
        xmlContent += '<article class="post all ' + records[i].getElementsByTagName("CATEGORY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '" id="">'
            + '<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail">'
            + '<img src="' + records[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '" />'
            + '<div class="caption">'
            + '<a href="' + records[i].getElementsByTagName("LINK")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '">'
            + '<h4>' + records[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</h4>'
            + '</a>'
            + '<p>' + records[i].getElementsByTagName("SHORTDESCRIPTION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</p>'
            + '</div>'
            + "</div></div></article>";
    }
    xmlContent += "</div>";
    content.innerHTML = xmlContent;

    var paginationContent = "";
    if (page > 1) {
        paginationContent += ' <a href="javascript:paganation('+(page - 1)+');">Back</a> ';
    } else {
        paginationContent += " Back ";
    }

    for (var j = 1; j <= maxPages; j++) { // <----------- <= instead of <
        paginationContent += ' <a href="javascript:paganation('+j+');">'+j+'</a> ';
    }

    var next = page + 1;
    if (next <= maxPages) {
        paginationContent += ' <a href="javascript:paganation('+next+');">Next</a> ';
    } else {
        paginationContent += " Next ";
    }
    pagination.innerHTML = paginationContent;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/xml/product_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
records = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PRODUCT");
paganation(1);
```

Comment: That works for anything under 10 but anything over 10 for example 12 or 18 doesn't  show until you have 20

Comment: @Zachary1748 True, sorry, I just fixed that, see the new code.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much! I had one other question, how would go about randomizing the order of which the xml content is displayed?

Comment: Also I have just noticed that if I have anything more then 14 products/nodes in my xml file that it stops showing it all of them.

Comment: Here is the error that is shown in the console; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

It is saying that error is coming from this line of code; records = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PRODUCT");

Comment: I have noticed it is part of my XML causing this because I narrowed it down to where I could view most of the products except for about 10 items. Please look at updated XML close to the bottom of the XML in the original post.

Comment: I had illegal characters in my nodes, I have fixed it myself. Thanks for the help!